# npm dependancies installation, confused

Tags: node.js, npm

I've two installations of node.js/npm , one is 1.4.28 and one is 3.1.0

by deploying the same app with the package.json file containing:

```
    {
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "js server",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.3.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1.36",
    "body-parser": "^1.13.2",
    "ejs": "^2.3.2",
    "express": "^4.13.1",
    "generic-pool": "^2.2.0",
    "multer": "^0.1.8",
    "mysql": "^2.7.0",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.3",
    "nodemailer": "^1.4.0",
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^1.0.3",
    "password-hash-and-salt": "^0.1.2",
    "pm2": "^0.14.3",
    "redis": "^0.12.1",
    "redis-sessions": "^0.3.9",
    "request": "^2.58.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.5",
    "winston": "^1.0.1",
    "yauzl": "^2.3.1"
  }
}
```

on the version 1.4.28 , after running npm install on a fresh installation without any node_modules directory, if fills with the correct required modules:

[image]

while on the version 3.1.0 I get tons of subdependancies that should not been needed in my opinion:

[image]

So anyone could explain me what's going on and why I get all those deps pulled in ?  I've also tried with --production what on npm with no success...

Thanks a lot !

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35227212/580651) on how to use legacy bundling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's new npm 3.* feature. From npm [blog](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5):

> With npm@3, your node_modules directory will be a lot flatter. All of
>   your dependencies and most of your subdependencies (and
>   (sub)+dependencies) will be sitting next to each other at the top
>   level. Only when there are conflicts will modules be installed at
>   deeper levels. This should make things a lot easier for Windows users.