# How to avoid downloading all npm packages

Tags: npm, create-react-app

While experimenting with React, I've come across the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) GitHub project. As instructed, I did:

> npm install -g create-react-app
>
> create-react-app my-app
>
> cd my-app

The issue here is 'node_modules' folder is full of npm packages rather than having only dependencies.

I'd like to know why this is happening and how can I fix this in order to download only dependencies.

Comment: node_modules includes all the dependencies (dependencies in your package.json) of your project plus their dependencies. You need all these node modules to successfully run the project.

Comment: @ShanilFernando I understand the dependency concept, but I feel like it's too much. I pasted the directory content here: https://pastebin.com/VKdy2viT. The folder size 200 MB. Could you please check if you have time?

Comment: Yes I know, All these are dependencies. You can test this by copying the `package.json` file into a different folder and manually running `npm install`. Then you will see that all these are dependencies. BTW, they are 200 MB because they are coming with the source code and lot of source code are not uglified. `create-react-app` just create the file structure according to the predefined boilerplate.

Comment: @ShanilFernando Indeed, same modules were downloaded. Thank you very much for your help, I understand how it works now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm dependancies installation, confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317925/npm-dependancies-installation-confused)